# Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory for react application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heap-memory

Hi I am facing *Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory* error for my react application. I have tried increasing the NodeJS memory allocation up-to 8Gb. but nothing is working. Any possible solutions or workaround will be helpful.

```
node  : v12.16.1
npm   : v6.13.4
react : v16.12.0
```

Comment: If this is happening in webpack (or something like that) this would be quite weird. Step 1 for me would be to at least make sure all my dependences are up to date.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Evert for your suggestion. I am actually working on upgrading typescript version of my react app from 3.8.3 to the latest (i.e. 4.8.3) and observing this memory issue.
The recent logs says:  "Issues checking service aborted - probably out of memory. Check the `memoryLimit` option in the ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin configuration.
If increasing the memory doesn't solve the issue, it's most probably a bug in the TypeScript or EsLint."
So seems like its a issue with typescript or EsLint